# TypeError 'NoneType' even after a typecheck python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable even after checking type

```
print(type(order))
print(len(order))
if type(order['shipmentItems']) is not None:
   for item in order['shipmentItems']: # ----- errors here
```

the for loop iterates through once through before calling the error

Comment: `type(None)` is a special class colloquially printed as `NoneType` (though that name is not visible in Python's global scope). In particular, `None` is not a type, even though type hinting confusingly uses `None` to *mean* `NoneType` during static analysis.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Although it's [now exposed as `types.NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#types) as of... *checks watch*... whenever they officially release `3.10.0` (it was tagged within the last day or two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply test `if my_object is not None`, not `if type(my_object) is not None`

```
>>> type(None) is None
False
>>> type(None)
<class 'NoneType'>  # Python 3.9.x
```

This is effectively the comparison that you're making, which will never be `True`.

You can also use:

```
for item in order.get('shipmentItems', []):
```

to simplify instead, iterating over an empty list if the key is missing, or the key is present but the value is falsey.

Reproduction of where you're getting tripped up:

```
>>> order = {}
>>> order['shipmentItems'] = None
>>> type(order['shipmentItems']) is not None
True
>>> order['shipmentItems'] is not None
False
```

Comment: Just to be clear, when the value is `None`, `type(value)` is returning `NoneType`, the internal class that `None` is the only instance of ([until 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#types), the only way to even see `NoneType` was to do `type(None)`; it wasn't an exposed name).